# Can we stop or remove animation effect on focus with UIButton and give other border effect tvOS

Tags: swift, tvos, tvml

In the below delegate function I was trying to do but did'nt get desired result

```
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext,withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if (context.nextFocusedView == self) {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
            self.animationDidStop(CAAnimation(), finished: true)
            }, completion: { () -> Void in

        })

    }
    else {
        // handle unfocused appearance changes

        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
            self.animationDidStop(CAAnimation(), finished: true)
            }, completion: { () -> Void in

        })
    }
    context.nextFocusedView?.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero
    context.nextFocusedView?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9;
    context.nextFocusedView?.layer.shadowRadius = 0;
    context.nextFocusedView?.layer.shadowColor= UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor
    context.previouslyFocusedView?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what you did get and how it differs from your desired result?

Comment: Setting your `UIButton` as a custom type should remove the default focus effects.

Comment: @CoryTrese I want to remove animation effect on focus and put some shadow or border to the UIButton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you have to set your button type to **Custom type**. By custom type you will get no more system animations, so you have to do all animations by yourself.

Then you can implement **didUpdateFocusInContext** method either in **UIViewController** or you can make your own **UIButton** subclass if there are more button types on a single screen.

Here is a code that I use in my *UIButton* subclass. This will provide the button enlargement along with red border on focus and will get to normal state on focus loss.

```
let scale = 1.1    
layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {

    if context.nextFocusedView == self {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in

            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale)
            self.layer.borderWidth = 2

            }, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in

            self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            self.layer.borderWidth = 0

            }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Using XCode8 and tvOS 10 Beta, this isn't working. The transforms animate, but the layer animations do not occur. I tried this will several animatable properties of the layer and non of them animated.

Comment: I added an extension but I get this when adding your code: Method does not override any method from its superclass. Would be nice if you give the whole solution.